# How to access virtual directory in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-directory

I created a virtual directory in IIS. My project is hosted in D:/ and I want to access C:/ from my project. So, I created a virtual directory to C:/ in IIS. Now, how do I access this virtual directory from Asp.net?

Comment: can't make anything out of this - what are you trying to do?

Comment: this is a very bad thing you've done. localize all resources you need in a single virtual directory or a directory in your web root. what you have done would allow any web user the ability to look at all your files and folders, and it won't even help you do what you are trying.

Comment: C:\ is just an example. please read the comment that I made below.

Comment: If you would like to access specific files from a certain location, then you can share the folder and provide access to the 'ASPNET' user. This folder can then be accessed from your C# code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding virtual directories.

Virtual directories allow the **client** to access resources from the server.
**You should not make `C:\` a virtual directory.**

Your ASP.Net **server-side** code can access anything in the server filesystem, without any special configuration.

Comment: "Virtual directories allow the client to access resources from the server." this is exactly what I want but I wont point to C:\, this is just an example. What I really want to do is I want to access directory from another server to compare some files in hosted server.